# Excel Compare Values in two columns in a single row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

I want to *compare two columns* in a row likewise, as the image provided

[image]

I searched the whole internet(to my knowledge) but didn't find the thing I'm looking for

Hope somebody can help me

Comment: i tried the macro's but they are not providing the results i want     _I'm a complete newbie_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA function you can use:

```
Public Function ListMissingWords(WordsToSearch As String, TextToSearch As String) As String
    Dim AllWords As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim TempResult As String

    On Error GoTo ErrLabel

    AllWords = Split(WordsToSearch, ",")
    For i = LBound(AllWords) To UBound(AllWords)
        If Not InStr(LCase(TextToSearch), LCase(AllWords(i))) > 0 Then
            TempResult = TempResult & AllWords(i) & ","
        End If
    Next i
    If TempResult <> "" Then
        TempResult = Left(TempResult, Len(TempResult) - 1)
    End If
    ListMissingWords = TempResult

    Exit Function
ErrLabel:
    Err.Clear
End Function
```

To insert it:

- press Alt+F11 in Excel
- right click on your workbook's name and select "insert" - "module"
- insert the code

Now you can use this function in your workbook:

[image]

You'll need to save your file as a macro-enabled Excel workbook (.xlsm)

Comment: Hello, Mate Juhasz  i tried as you said but I'm not able run the macro because it doesn't show in the macro list  View>Macro>View Macro  i'm attaching the images ![Valid XHTML](http://i.imgur.com/ays1r8P.png). ![Valid XHTML](http://i.imgur.com/msRFFmq.png).

Comment: Functions are not supposed to show up there. You should use it as a function, please see formula (in formula bar) in my screenshot

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at the image first time,  i did as you mentioned but again there is problem ![Error](http://i.imgur.com/vJGVWgA.png).

Comment: It's probably due to different regional settings:( I've modified it, hope it now works.

Comment: Same error as before @Máté Juhász

Comment: please try to debug it (by pressing F9 you can insert a breakpoint which forces compiler to go debugging, then run it step by step by F8)

Comment: I tried as you said but the F8 is not doing anything like it goes to next step right? it doesn't go anywhere it just stops at the starting breakpoint(no yellow coloured text after F8) [F8 press](http://i.imgur.com/pH06zsY.png)

Comment: after placing the breakpoint, you need to start the macro, by editing one of the formulas in the sheet

Comment: or just place a simple sub: `Sub Test() Debug.Print # ListMissingWords("a","a") # End Sub` where # is for newline

Comment: i did that previously i mean after putting breakpoint i typed again the formula in 1st cell and draged it down

Comment: macro error [Not Saving](http://i.imgur.com/1ommm5l.png)

Comment: It'd be much more easy if you would read my text at first.... "# is for newline" Place it as a new sub, not within the function.

Comment: Sorry i gave the wrong image i did put in the end (after End Function) with # and continue with subject, if you provided me with a image i would be glad, Sorry my understanding in excel is somewhat lacking [Image}(http://i.imgur.com/DDSEIKC.png)

Comment: Sub Test() <NEWLINE> Debug.Print  ListMissingWords("a","a") <NEWLINE> End Sub

Comment: same as before it is highlighting in red colour

Comment: Juhasz, it worked in my personal laptop don't know why it didn't work in ma office but its working i'm grateful for you help and sorry for my lack of knowledge.....:-D

Comment: [Working](http://i.imgur.com/STeOkiB.png) you saved a lot of my time by helping me otherwise i have to do it manually for a month or more maybe